# Protecting an API with Duende Server

Tags: .net-core, .net-7.0, duende-identity-server

I am currently trying to develop an authentication system to log in a user and give permission to access an API.

The API only has a controller that returns all the claims the user has:

```
[Route("identity")]
[Authorize]
public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
    }
}
```

On my API I have set up the JWT authentication and authorization:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("database_conn");

// Identity
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
});

builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDBContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;

        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "api1");
    })
);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
    options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
    {
        policy.AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyOrigin();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("default");

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

When I try to reach the /identity endpoint after succesfully authenticating the user, I am redirected to localhost:6001/Account/Login which doesn't exist, it should be redirected to localhost:5001/Account/Login if there is no user authenticated.

The client I am using has the proper redirect links:

```
 new Client
{
    ClientId = "js",
    ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequireClientSecret = false,

    RedirectUris =           { "https://localhost:5003/callback.html" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5003/index.html" },

    AllowOfflineAccess = true,

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
        "api1"
    },
    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding
}
```

The Duende Server is getting back a cookie and a JWT token that contain all the claims that should be necessary to validate if the user is authenticated or not.

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "DA4EE3153F56DF0877C3DDE4766DAB7B",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
},
{
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001",
  "nbf": 1705681216,
  "iat": 1705681216,
  "exp": 1705684816,
  "aud": "https://localhost:5001/resources",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "api1"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "client_id": "js",
  "sub": "some-user-id",
  "auth_time": 1705681215,
  "idp": "local",
  "sid": "04830986C58DCDD600C25B1CB0A93093",
  "jti": "43EF5683A3ACA0041852B326F6620A9A"
}
```

App.js

```
/// <reference path="oidc-client.js" />

function log() {
    document.getElementById("results").innerText = "";

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, function (msg) {
        if (msg instanceof Error) {
            msg = "Error: " + msg.message;
        } else if (typeof msg !== "string") {
            msg = JSON.stringify(msg, null, 2);
        }
        document.getElementById("results").innerText += msg + "\r\n";
    });
}

document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", login, false);
document.getElementById("api").addEventListener("click", api, false);
document.getElementById("logout").addEventListener("click", logout, false);

var config = {
    authority: "https://localhost:5001",
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "openid profile api1",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5003/index.html",
};
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);

mgr.events.addUserSignedOut(function () {
    log("User signed out of IdentityServer");
});

mgr.getUser().then(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        log("User logged in", user.profile);
    } else {
        log("User not logged in");
    }
});

function login() {
    mgr.signinRedirect();
}

function api() {
    mgr.getUser().then(function (user) {
        console.log("user:", user)
        fetch('https://localhost:6001/identity', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + user.access_token,
            },
        })
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
}

function logout() {
    mgr.signoutRedirect();
}
```

I do not see what I did wrong to get a different redirect than I was expecting and why the API does not recognize that the user is authenticated and has the proper authorization to get back info from it.

Comment: My recommendation is to separate IdentityServer, the client, and the API in separate projects. The current code really doesn't make any sense. you usually use AddOpenIDConnect in the client to authenticate and usually the redirect URI i in the client definitions should be /signin-oidc (back to AddOpenIDConnect)

Comment: I currently have, as you said, the IdentityServer, the client and API seperated (I forgot to add the app.js because it kept telling me my post was spam).
I have edited the post.

Comment: exactly what request is failing for you? also, I did blog about debugging jwtbearer problems here https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: When I try accessing the API, for example with a request https://localhost:6001/identity, it gives me a 302 and redirects me to https://localhost:6001/Account/Login when that route doesn't even exist.

Comment: in the API you have , builder.Services.AddIdentity, why? A pure API do usually not need that.  So I guess it catches the request before it reaches JWT-bearer. you can in the ASp.NET Core log probably see what middleware/services caues the 302. when you get a 302, then it is not JwtBearer that generates that response, it mainly only returns 401 and 403. are you sure you use HTTPS, otherwise app.UseHttpsRedirection(); can cause a redirect.

Comment: I am using the identity in the API because I need to manage logins and registrations, therefore needing the services to manage users. I will try to see the logs. And yes I am using HTTPS.
I will try to check all of these during the weekend and I'll give feedback as soon as I can. Thank you for your input so far.

Comment: You said "I currently have, as you said, the IdentityServer, the client and API seperated", so I assume that the API was a pure api. I suspect that ASP.NET Identity kicks in and takes over... do try to "temporary" disable Identity in the API.

Comment: I did disable the identity on the API real quick and got a 401 as intended. So I guess I should try and see how else I'd do it without Identity inside the API.

Comment: it can also an idea to review the order of the middlewares in the request pipeline. I started to write an answer on your qeuestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that ASP.NET Identity is mixed with JwtBearer, and ASP.NET Identity takes over the request before JwtBearer has a chance to process it. My recommendation is to review the order of the middlewares in the request pipeline.

The only status codes you should see from the JWtBearer itself are 401 and 403. If you get redirects, then it is not from JwtBearer.

Comment: Thank you, after removing the Identity middleware I was able to get a proper HTTP code that was expected.

Comment: Great! Glad you solved it!